# How to compute the major unit of a numeric axis

Tags: actionscript-3, charts, rounding

I want to display three labels on the y-axis: `min`, `middle` and `max`. max - min = 9572.
The easiest way to find middle is 9572 / 2 = 4786. These values are not nice so Excel would probably increase the interval to 1000 and set `middle` to 500.

How do I compute nice values for my y-axis when `min` and `max` are given?  `min` and/or `max` might be negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question! Recently I had solved similar problem recently and what I have done:

1. Create an array of possible steps, something like [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 75, 100, 200, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 2000, 2500, 5000, 7500, 10000]
2. Determine how many labels you need - I guess it's 3
3. Choose step from an array. 9572 / (3 - 1) = 4786, nearest step is 5000. You may compare distance to next and previous steps and do custom rounding here, for example, if non-rounded step is 20% less than next step, choose next step, otherwise previous one.
4. Choose good looking starting point for min label. Take your actual minimum, divide by chosen step (5000). Round the result (you can use `floor` for minimum and `ceil` for maximum) and multiply it by chosen step. For example, if min = -3400 and max = 2700:

   scaleMin = floor(-3400 / 5000) * 5000 = -5000
   scaleMax = ceil(2700 / 5000) * 5000 = 5000

This will give three labels: -5000, 0 and 5000. If you can tolerate last mark on y-axis *below* graph maximum, don't just use ceil (or floor). Compute how much percents graph maximum is off the mark, and add one step if it's too much.

Answer (score 0):

Might help to provide an implementation in C#. My sample might not work for negative y-axis values. Hope it helps someone!

```
private double GetMajorStep(double yAxisMax)
    {
        int[] stepArray = {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 75, 100, 200, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 2000, 2500, 5000, 7500, 10000, 20000, 50000,100000, 500000,1000000};
        const int numLabels = 2;
        var stepSize = (int) (yAxisMax/(numLabels - 1));
        var possibleSteps = stepArray.Where(p => p < stepSize).ToList();
        if (!possibleSteps.Any()) return stepSize;

        var nearest = possibleSteps.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((long)x - stepSize)).First();
        return nearest;
    }
```